# creating an empty file from diff using svn patch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, patch

I'm trying to move a version-controlled directory between two repositories using TortoiseSVN.

Simply copying the directory is not sufficient because I also want to move all `svn:ignore` properties, so I tried to create a patch: I opened the log (history) selected all revisions of the directory in question and exported a cumulative diff. I applied the patch to the target folder. For safety I compared the created dir with the (exported) original dir using WinMerge and found **one empty file missing**.

Surprisingly the diff contained this file:

```
Index: Project/SomeDir/SomeFile.cs
===================================================================
--- Project/SomeDir/SomeFile.cs (nicht existent)
+++ Project/SomeDir/SomeFile.cs (Revision 112)
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
 + ﻿   
\ No newline at end of file
```

I found that [GNU patch](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/patch-Options.html#index-patch-options) has a switch for removing empty files after applying a patch:

> -E
>   --remove-empty-files

```
Remove output files that are empty after the patches have been applied. See Creating and Removing.
```

...and I expect a corresponding switch to be present in my svn client (`svn patch`). Is there such an option? Which patch tool is invoked? The command line help of svn doesn't answer both questions.